# If $A$ is a measurable subset of $X$ then is any $B \subset A$ also measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a set, and $A\subset X$. If $A$ is measurable, then is it true that $B \subset A$ is also measurable?

Comment: What is your stance on the axiom of choice?

Comment: No. In $\mathbb{R}$ there is famous example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $X= \mathbb R$, $A =[0,1]$. We know that there is a non-measurable subset of $A$ which we may call vitali set.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the axiom of choice, it is not true. Take $A=\Bbb R$, for instance. Let $B\subset \Bbb R$ be a Vitali set, it is easy to see that $B\subset A$, $A$ is (Lebesgue) measurable but $B$ is not measurable.

However, if you do not assume choice, there is framework called [the Solovay model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model) such that every subset of $\Bbb R$ is Lebesgue measurable. In this case, your assertion can be trivially verified since every sets are measurable...

Beware, however, that this is not the standard way how things are done and Solovay model introduces some "problems" of its own that are not founded in the usual model (ZFC).